# How to fix a GitHub hosted blog post URL and Project Page URL collision?

Tags: github, url, github-pages

I have hosted my blog via GitHub pages along with a custom CNAME - praveenpuglia.com. A few days ago I created a project named show-me-my-colors and the project page for it had the URL -

http://praveenpuglia.com/show-me-my-colors

Now today, I idiotically pushed a blog post with the same URL which has overridden the project page may be?

How do I get back the project page back on that URL? I don't want to change the URL of the project page!

Answer (score 1):

I had this wild idea in head of pushing a fake commit to the project gh-pages branch and let it rebuilt itself and this magically worked! :)